# How many combinations are possible keeping the sum constant

Tags: probability, permutations

How many combinations of numbers are possible keeping the sum of its digits as a constant.
 My problem is like this :-
How many numbers are possible keeping the sum = 9 between 9 and 9000 ? ie,

```
0 0 0 9
0 0 1 8
0 0 2 7
0 0 3 6
0 0 4 5
.
.
.
1 0 0 8
1 0 1 7

.
.
.
8 0 0 1

.
.
9 0 0 0
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your sum can be stored in a single digit, this is akin to distributing 9 indistinguishable balls among 4 distinguishable baskets ((9+4-1) over 9).

Comment: $9$ indistinguishable balls among $4$ distinguishable baskets with unlimited capacity, that is.

Comment: Yes of course, thank you.

Comment: @Guest86 `((9+4-1) over 4)` ?Is there any way to relate it to permutation and combination. Because I have to use the formula in a `matlab` code

Comment: @noufal: The intended meaning was $\binom{9+4-1}4$, which is the number of $4$-combinations of $9+4-1=12$ items. For an explanation why this is the answer to your question, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).